# How to get education and work history of facebook user by fb app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I tried all options even if search so many apis couldn't find any answer..i checked the facebook http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#requesting-extended-permissions  there i have to set up parameter in scope but found that so many people complained that they are still getting the error or facebook shut that down for api access..

facebook permisions:http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Can anyone step in to help us?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Though it is very late for answering question, it will help somebody. That's why answering this question. Try this fql query.

```
dynamic friends = fbApp.Query("SELECT uid, name, pic_square, work_history,
 education_history, current_location, profile_url, email FROM user WHERE uid  = me()");
```

This gives all user info with work history and education history.